# Can I replace two 15 amp fuses with 10 and 20 amp fuses?

Tags: circuit-breaker, electrical-panel

[image: Fuse Box]

Currently I have 4 x 15 amps fuses. My question is: Can I change the left fuse shown in the image with a 10 amps fuse and make the other 20 amps? Would that work?

Edit:

[image]

There's another one behind the fridge that I can't take a picture of but I think they're identical. So 2 outlets in total.

Comment: What size is the wire feeding the kitchen sockets?

Comment: Unfortunately this picture is all the infomation I have. We're renting and the super is not willing to help.

Comment: Then why do you want to mess with this?

Comment: Cause we need to use the microwave and the fridge at the same time.

Comment: What size wire is at the outlet? Is there more than 1 outlet(s) if 12 awg wire and at least 2 outlets (1 duplex outlet ) you could upsize to a 20 amp fuse.

Comment: Is there an easy way to check the wire size?

Comment: Can you show a picture of the outlets?  If they are installed correctly they will indicate the circuit capacity.  Item 2 in answer below.

Comment: Sure. I've edited the post.

Comment: @Dave You cannot tell circuit ampacity by the type of outlet, a single duplex is 2 outlets and is code compliant to be used on a 20 amp circuit see NEC table 210.21.B.2, and 210.21.3.

Comment: I recall last year that 2 of the fuses burned and my super had a bunch of fuses 15s and 20s and changed them with whatever ones that are working. So oringinally, it might have been 20 amp fuse. I know this is confusing sorry.

Comment: If the super is just throwing around15s and 20s like they're candy then you may have more problems than just the microwave tripping a breaker.

Answer (score 1):

### Nope, either way

First, "upgrading" the 15A fuse is not allowed.   A few people are talking about the rules by which the circuit *might've* been wired for 20A.  That's dreaming.  If the circuit met those requirements, **they would've used a 20A fuse in the first place** and you wouldn't be having this discussion now.  So I wouldn't go getting my hopes up on that.

Now, it's not illegal to swap the 15 for a 10. However, it's a bad idea because then, the next guy won't know what fuse is supposed to go there.   You may notice something about that fuse box, **there is absolutely nothing on the box that tells you what the fuse *should* be**.

That 30A rating is the rating of the fuse box itself.  It is saying that you could hypothetically use that fuse box with dual 30A fuses, 10AWG wire and feed an electric dryer.  However in your case, the wire is almost certainly #14 AWG, which only allows 15 amps.

I would be surprised if the refrigerator were the "other" appliance.  They tend to be quite low draw unless they are older units, and if they are older units, most electric companies will be happy to give you a new fridge, because it's cheaper than adding generating  capacity to power your old one... and I would be amazed if your landlord would oppose a free new fridge.  He probably just hasn't bothered to ask because he doesn't pay the electric bill and doesn't have time to deal with it.  This is an opportunity for you.

Now it may be a different appliance, perhaps one that you consider inconsequential, because most people frankly don't know what devices draw.  They think "$20 toaster must draw a tiny fraction of the huge expensive fridge" nope, it's the exact opposite.  If you can identify that other appliance, that may solve it.

Most kitchen appliances which use heat use 1500 watts (12.5 amps) whether large or small.  It wouldn't matter if you had a brand new house with fresh 20A wiring, no kitchen circuit can support two 1500W (12.5 amp) appliances at once.

It's also possible you have a large deluxe microwave that pulls 1500+ watts and cannot share a 15A circuit.  Take it back and get a 1000W mini.

Comment: I have seen older equipment wired with 10 awg and fused at 15 amps this is rare, but number 12 used on a fixed ampacity panel is not uncommon in the Pacific northwest.

Comment: I recall last year that 2 of the fuses burned and my super had a bunch of fuses 15s and 20s and changed them with whatever ones that are working. So oringinally, it might have been 20 amp fuse. I know this is confusing sorry.

Comment: @Harout then you're really at square one.  I would just go to the hardware store and get more fuses, they are readily available in any community that has a lot of older homes.

Answer (score 0):

#### Probably not...

Each fuse has to meet three requirements to be **SAFE**:

1. Suitable for the fuse panel. That **appears** to be satisfied by the "30 AMPS" marking for each pair of fuses.
2. No larger than the receptacle or equipment ratings. As a general rule, the receptacles and or hardwired equipment ratings need to match the fuse/circuit breaker ratings. If you have a 15 Amp receptacle (identified normally by two straight vertical slots + ground) then you normally use only a **15 Amp** fuse as a 20 Amp fuse would allow more current than the receptacle is rated for. However, if everything else is OK then you can switch a 15 Amp receptacle for a 20 Amp receptacle (identified normally by one of the vertical slots replaced with a "T"). As @EdBeal pointed out, you could also have multiple 15 Amp receptacles on a 20 Amp circuit (this is a little different from the rules for a lot of other circuits), but you will still need to satisfy the wire size requirements (12 gauge) for a 20 Amp circuit.
3. Wire size. This is usually the big problem. For a 20 Amp circuit you need at least **12 gauge**  wire. A 15 Amp circuit requires **14 gauge** wire (counter-intuitively, a higher # wire gauge is actually smaller wire that can carry less current). Unless you are 100% certain that all wire from the receptacle to the fuse panel is at least 12 gauge, you **MUST NOT** use a 20 Amp fuse. The problem is that replacing a fuse takes 10 seconds and replacing a receptacle takes a few minutes. Replacing the wire can take a **lot** more time & effort.

Harper's answer made me think of one more thing. The "label" says Kitchen, Room Sockets. In addition to the refrigerator or other items that you know are on the circuit, there may be other receptacles and/or lights in other rooms on the same circuit. If the microwave pulls 1500 Amps and you have a few hundred watts of lighting (which is just a few incandescent bulbs if you're still using those), TV or other stuff then that could easily get you over the 15 Amp limit even if the refrigerator itself, when the compressor isn't running, uses very little power. So you may want to turn off "everything you can find" - e.g., all lights, fans, TV, computer, etc. - everything except the refrigerator and the microwave. Then run the microwave for a couple of minutes and see if the breaker trips. Or alternatively, the next time it trips go around the house and see what else isn't working - maybe some lights that you didn't realize were connected to the same circuit. You might just find some additional load that can be turned off when you use the microwave and then have it work without tripping the breaker every time.

Alternatively, unless you are lucky enough to have 12 gauge wire on the circuit, getting a lower power microwave may be the easiest solution.

Comment: This is not accurate a 20 amp circuit with 2 ea 15 amp outlets is code compliant, the op wants to use 2 devices at the same time so if 12 gauge wire it would be legal.

Comment: @EdBeal He could have 10 15 Amp receptacles all in use. My understanding is that the OP wants to upsize one receptacle (and therefore circuit) to 20 Amp for a microwave oven, which led to the somewhat logical "30 Amps = 15 + 15 and 30 Amps = 20 + 10".

Comment: @EdBeal Actually, I think we agree on the main point - **12 gauge wire** is the key. The rest is either easy (replace a fuse and/or receptacle) or simply not a problem at all.

Comment: I'll be using the microwave oven and the fridge on the same outlet. The other outlet is used for light amp stuff. Currently when I start the microwave oven for more than 20 seconds I'm losing power on that section.

Comment: "losing power" - as in "lights dim" or as in "fuse blows"?

Comment: As you can see the lower left one in the picture has a button on it. I have to click that the start everything back.

Comment: As you can see the lower right one in the picture has a button on it. I have to click that the start everything back.

Comment: OK. You are tripping a 15-amp breaker - I didn't notice before that it is a breaker in fuse form factor. So we get back to the key question of "what size wire do you have going between that fuse/breaker and receptacles?" in order to decide whether you can safely & legally swap the 15 for 20.

Comment: See NEC table 210.21.B.2 . a single duplex is legal on a 20 amp circuit. , 20 amp kitchen devices are very rare I find the high power or commercial units are usually 208/220v

Comment: How can I tell the wire size between the breaker and the receptacles?

Comment: With the fuse/breaker out, open up the receptacle and measure using an appropriate tool - there are a few types. Find the tool first.